Наполненные глаголы
Ученица пришла от репетитора с понятием "наполненные глаголы". В Интернете не нашла материал об этом. Подскажите, что имеется в виду?

Может, термин неточный.  Есть глаголы § 86. Предельные / непредельные глаголы   https://studfile.net/preview/407670/page:65/   Есть  понятие недостаточные и изобилующие глаголы https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1786567-kak-privesti-primery-nedostatochnyh-i-izobilujuschih-glagolov.html

А может, имелось в виду смысловые глаголы? Т.е.  наполненные смыслом. Авторский термин, как сейчас модно говорить. Авторский курс, авторский метод, авторская технология. Следует уточнить у репетитора.

Автор почему-то молчит.

Есть понятие аргументная структура глагола. Возможно, наполненными глаголами можно назвать  глагол с полной аргументной структурой.  Например, у переходных глаголов обязательным аргументом является прямое дополнение.
Предикат/глагол и его аргументы (актанты) образуют структуру предикат-аргумент.
НЕМНОГО ТЕОРИИ https://studfile.net/preview/7467227/
Актанты
Акта́нт (фр. actant — «действующий») в лингвистике — активный, значимый участник ситуации, речевая конструкция, заполняющая семантическую или синтаксическую валентность предиката-глагола. Актант - термин предложен Л. Теньером (1959) и первоначально обозначал активного участника ситуации, действующее лицо (отсюда название, букв. ’действующий’). Актантом может быть подлежащее, дополнение, в общем, все, что может сочетаться с предикатом.
Типы актантов:
Агенс (подлежащее): тот, кто выполняет действие.
Пациенс (прямое дополнение): тот, на кого направлено действие.
Адресат (косвенное дополнение): тот, кому адресовано действие.
Инструмент: то, чем выполняется действие.
Локатив: место, где происходит действие.
Иерархия актантов:
Между актантами устанавливается иерархия: выделяются I актант, II актант, III актант и т. д. В предложении: Завтра я подарю тебе книгу I актант —я, II актант — книгу, III актант — тебе.
Это различие между актантами определяется их «степенью необходимости»: по определению, присутствие всех актантов обязательно, однако легко видеть, что опущение разных актантов в различной степени сказывается на полноте синтаксической структуры, например: Я подарю книгу — в меньшей степени «ущербное» предложение, чем Я подарю тебе. Соответственно книгу — это II актант, а тебе — III актант.
Обязательные  и факультативные  валентности глагола
Подчиненные синтакс. единицы делятся на актанты и сирконстанты. Актанты — функц. единицы, присутствие к-х отражает обязательные валентности глагола-сказуемого, т. е. валентности, к-е должны быть заполнены в неэллиптическом предложении. Сирконстанты — функц. единицы, присутствие к-х отражает факультативные валентности глагола-сказуемого. Напр., в Завтра я подарю тебе книгу слова я, тебе, книгу - актанты, т.к. без них предл. будет неполным, а слово завтра сирконстант, т.к. его отсутствие не превращает предл. в эллиптическое.
Типы предикатов по валентностям https://studfile.net/preview/3543152/page:16/
Предикаты обладают семантической валентностью — способностью сочетаться с теми или иными актантами. Количество и качество актантов определяется семантикой предиката. Термины, отражающие валентность предиката, - «одноактантный», «двухактантный» и т.д. или «одноместный», «двухместный» и т.д. Большинство предикатов относятся к одноместным и двухместным, достаточно распространены и трехместные предикаты. Далее в источнике - подробно.

Интересна аналогия с математикой: функция и ее аргументы.  Тогда глагол - это функция F = f ( x, y, z ).
